# Class error: Definitions of property procedures for the same property are inconsistent

Tags: excel, vba, class, oop

I am trying to create my first class.

```vb
'CLASS Disponent

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    m_dispocode = 1
    m_name = Unknown
    m_suppliers
    m_materials
    SetID
End Sub

Private m_materials As New ArrayList
Private m_suppliers As New ArrayList
Private m_name As String
Private m_dispocode
Private m_id As String

Property Get Id() As Integer
    Id = m_id
End Property

Property Get Suppliers(value As Integer) As String
If value >= 0 And value < m_suppliers.Count Then
    Suppliers = m_suppliers(value)
Else
    Err.Raise ERROR_INVALID_INDEXING, "ReadWorksheet", "The indexer used in the arraw is out of bounds"
End If
End Property

Property Let Suppliers(supp As String)
    m_suppliers.Add supp
End Property

Property Get Dispocode() As Integer
    Dispocode = m_dispocode
End Property

Property Let Dispocode(dispcode As Integer)
If dispcode > 0 And dispcode < 1000 Then
    m_dispocode = dispcode
Else
    Err.Raise ERROR_INVALID_DISPOCODE, "ReadWorksheet", "The value must be between 1 (incl) and 999 (incl)"
End If
End Property

Property Get name() As String
    name = m_name
End Property

Property Let name(name As String)
If Len(name) > 3 Then
    m_name = name
Else
    Err.Raise ERROR_INVALID_NAME, "ReadWorksheet", "The name must be at least 3 letters long"

End Property

Property Get Materials(indexof As Integer) As ArrayList
If indexof >= 0 And indexof < m_suppliers.Count Then
    Materials = m_materials(indexof)
Else
    Err.Raise ERROR_INVALID_INDEXING, "ReadWorksheet", "The indexer used in the arraw is out of bounds"
End If
End Property

Property Let Materials(materialnum As String)
     m_materials.Add materialnum
End Property

Public Sub SetID()
    m_id = m_name & m_dispocode
End Sub
```

This is how I try to create my objects in a SUB in a normal Module:

```vb
Sub GenerateDisponents()
Dim last_row As Long
last_row = Sheets("Disponents").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim Dispos As New Collection

For i = 1 To last_row
    Dim temp As New Disponent
    
    Dim name As String
    name = Sheets("Disponents").Range("B" & i).value
    Dim code As Integer
    code = Sheets("Disponents").Range("A" & i).value
    
    temp.name = name
    temp.Dispocode = code
       
    Dispos.Add temp
    
    MsgBox ("DONE")
End Sub
```

When I try to run `GenerateDisponents` sub I get the following error on the Let Materials property:

> Definitions of property procedures for the same property are inconsistent, or property procedure has an optional parameter, a ParamArray, or an invalid Set final parameter.

For the early binding I use the following reference: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319.\mscorlib.dll`.

Comment: why aren't you calling `Class_Initialize()` right after you declare the instance of the class?

Comment: I suspect your `Err.Raise` procedures. Take them out temporarily and see if the code can run without them.

Comment: @Variatus I tried it. Didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: I would continue that way, take out parts of the Property Let procedure until there is nothing left that can offend. I would rem out a lot of code to make sure that it's really the one procedure you are examining that causes the error, just in case there is more than one.

Answer (score 1):

`Property Get Materials(indexof As Integer) As ArrayList` says an `ArrayList` is to be returned but `Property Let Materials(materialnum As String)` wants a `string` to be assigned to it - the property types must match.

As an array is backing this propery `obj.Materials = "Hello"` doesn't make much sense; you need to do what `ArrayList` does an use a `.Add()` / `.Item()` methods.

Is there a reason for using `ArrayList` rather than one of the built in types?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

A few notes:

1) Properties shouldn't raise errors. If you need to raise an error, change the property to a method.

2) I'd like to say "injected" but it's inaccurate, so I set an `IErrorHandler` through a property to handle errors in the class. You can change it to a method, e.g. `Init(ByVal objHandler as IErrorHandler)` or handle them as you like, but please don't show message-boxes through the class.

3) Lastly, I changed the `ArrayList` to a `Collection`.

**Disponent class:**

```
Option Explicit

Private m_errorHandler As IErrorHandler
Private m_materials As Collection
Private m_suppliers As Collection
Private m_name As String
Private m_dispocode As Integer
Private m_id As Integer

'// Properties
Property Let ErrorHandler(ByVal obj As IErrorHandler)
    Set m_errorHandler = obj
End Property

Property Get Id() As Integer
    Id = m_id
End Property

Property Get Name() As String
    Name = m_name
End Property

Property Let Material(ByVal materialnum As String)
     m_materials.Add materialnum
End Property

Property Let Supplier(ByVal supp As String)
    m_suppliers.Add supp
End Property

Property Get Dispocode() As Integer
    Dispocode = m_dispocode
End Property


'// Methods
Public Sub SetID()
    m_id = m_name & m_dispocode
End Sub

Public Function GetSupplier(ByVal index As Integer) As String
    On Error GoTo Trap

    If index <= 0 And index > m_suppliers.Count Then
        Err.Raise ERROR_INVALID_INDEXING, "ReadWorksheet", "The indexer used in the arraw is out of bounds"
    End If

    GetSupplier = m_suppliers(index)

Leave:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

Trap:
    HandleError Err.Description
    Resume Leave
End Function

Public Sub SetDispoCode(ByVal dispcode As Integer)
    On Error GoTo Trap

    If dispcode <= 0 And dispcode >= 1000 Then
        Err.Raise ERROR_INVALID_DISPOCODE, "ReadWorksheet", "The value must be between 1 (incl) and 999 (incl)"
    End If

    m_dispocode = dispcode

Leave:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

Trap:
    HandleError Err.Description
    Resume Leave
End Sub

Public Sub SetName(ByVal stringValue As String)
    On Error GoTo Trap

    If Len(Name) <= 3 Then
        Err.Raise ERROR_INVALID_NAME, "ReadWorksheet", "The name must be at least 3 letters long"
    End If

    m_name = Name

Leave:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

Trap:
    HandleError Err.Description
    Resume Leave
End Sub

Public Function GetMaterial(ByVal index As Integer) As String
    On Error GoTo Trap

    If index <= 0 And index > m_materials.Count Then
        Err.Raise ERROR_INVALID_INDEXING, "ReadWorksheet", "The indexer used in the arraw is out of bounds"
    End If

    GetMaterial = m_materials(index)

Leave:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

Trap:
    HandleError Err.Description
    Resume Leave
End Function

Private Sub HandleError(ByVal message As String)
    If Not m_errorHandler Is Nothing Then m_errorHandler.ShowError message 
End Sub

'Called automatically when the class is created
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
      m_dispocode = 1
      m_name = "Unknown"
      Set m_suppliers = New Collection
      Set m_materials = New Collection
      SetID
End Sub

'Called automatically when the class is destroyed
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set m_suppliers = Nothing
    Set m_materials = Nothing
    Set m_errorHandler = Nothing
End Sub
```

**A simple error handler:**

`IErrorHandler`

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ShowError(ByVal message As String)
End Sub
```

`ErrorHandler`

```
Option Explicit
Implements IErrorHandler

Private Sub IErrorHandler_ShowError(ByVal message As String)
    MsgBox message, vbCritical, "Error"
End Sub
```

**Testing:**

```
Sub GenerateDisponents()

    Dim last_row As Long
    last_row = Sheets("Disponents").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim Dispos As New Collection
    Dim errHandler As IErrorHandler: Set errHandler = New ErrorHandler
    Dim Name As String
    Dim code As Integer
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To last_row

        Dim temp As New Disponent
        temp.ErrorHandler = errHandler 

        Name = Sheets("Disponents").Range("B" & i).value
        code = Sheets("Disponents").Range("A" & i).value

        temp.SetName Name
        temp.SetDispoCode code

        Dispos.Add temp
    Next i


    MsgBox ("DONE")
End Sub
```